# ISPConfig shows the 403 forbidden

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

That's what i receive when opening the browser

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

and there is nothing meaningful in the logs

> " 403 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0"

and

> (13)Permission denied: access to / denied

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  but this was actually solved by adding the Apache user (www-data) to the ispconfig group in /etc/groups

> ispconfig:x:1003:www-data

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the web server was not able to access the requested file/folder because of insufficient permission error.

```
(13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

You need to make sure you apache user usually `www-data` can access the www root folder and the files contained in it such as index pages.

Comment: In particular, the `(13)` lets you know that this error refers to [filesystem permissions and not Apache configuration permissions](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) (such as `Deny from all` or rewrite rules with `[F]`).

Comment: @Ladadadada: Yes, I meant filesystem permissons issue not apache. Thanks for the clarification.